# Upload image to amazon s3 server with php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading, php-5.3

I have a problem with the upload of files to amazon, I stored an image to /var/tmp call 50.jpg, and I want to upload this image on this directory: `//bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/150x150/`. I use this class `https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class`. I tried like this :

```
S3::setAuth(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
S3::putObjectFile('/var/tmp/', 'bucket-name', '50.jpg', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ).
```

but not work.

Comment: You could also consider uploading the file to s3 directly via the browser :)

Comment: Yes, but I need to upload using php

Comment: The first argument must be a path to the file, so `/var/tmp/50.jpg` and not `/var/tmp/`; if you have set the proper error reporting you should see a warning

Comment: Ok, it works but upload is in this bucket but I want to upload in the folder `//bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/150x150/`

Comment: so, just change the path from `'50.jpg'` to `'150x150/50.jpg'`.